# Optimize ng-repeat for hundreds of static elements (log viewer)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The application I have has thousands of log lines. Each log line is static and will never change. Each log line is turned, inside the `ng-repeat`, into 5-10 DOM elements.

I've tried using `bindonce` but the benefits were almost non-existent. I also tried writing a custom directive which caches the compiled results:

```
.directive('logLine', function ($compile) {
    var template = $compile(logTemplate);
    var cache = {};
    return {
        scope: {
            line: '=logLine',
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            if (!cache.hasOwnProperty($scope.line.id)) {
                template($scope, function(cloned){
                    cache[$scope.line.id] = cloned;
                });
            }

            $element.html(cache[$scope.line.id]);
        }
    };
})
```

While this speeds up the program by around 30%, it still is really slow. My guess is, most of the time is spent removing and adding hundreds of DOM elements every time the page changes.

So my question is, is there any way to stop AngularJS from removing the DOM elements, and instead let me manually hide and display them later again? Or is there any other tricks to optimize this specific kind of application?

Comment: use pagination and filtering to minimize  rows in dom. A user can only digest so much information at one time anyway. Dom rendering is the slowest part

Comment: trty adding `track by id` to your ng-repeat and always remove/add items to the same array so that angular doesn't have to re-render everything (just the items added/removed). If that doesn't work your best bet is what @charlietfl said

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use one-time data bindings instead of two way data binding. All you need to do inside your ng-repeat is to prefix expressions to bind with ::. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="something in whatever">
  {{::something.var}}
</div>
```

See the [docs on one-time bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: As I mention, I've tried oncebind (as well as the one you mention). The gains were very small, from my debugging most of the slowdown is in creating and deleting DOM elements.